# How to run python script from Ansible and pass variable from the python script to Ansible to use later?

Tags: python, shell, ansible

I am trying to fetch my keyvalue (myP@ssw0rd) from AWS SSM Parameter store using python boto3.
Doing it in an Ansible playbook .yml file.
This is the python script that I am using:

```
 import boto3
 ssm = boto3.client(‘ssm’, region_name=‘us-east-1’)
 response=ssm.get_parameters(Names=[‘MyKeyName’])
 var_value= response[‘Parameters’][0][‘Value’]
```

I want to use this var_value inside my ansible play book like below:
Creating the DD agent

```
shell: DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 \
    docker run -d --name ddagent --network my-network -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    -e DD_API_KEY=$var_value \
    datadog/agent:latest
```

Here I am trying to fetch the value from SSM parameter store(using python boto3) and pass it to Ansible to use in “DD_API_KEY” in above command.
Can anyone please let me know what is best way to do it for this usecase?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the python script

```
print (var_value)
```

Run the python script using `command module` or `script module`(if you need to copy the script to remote machine) and register the output.

```
- name: run python script
  command: '/path/to/python-executable /home/centos/conf.d/ssmread/ddkeyreadssm.py'
  register: result

- name: creating DD agent
  shell: |
    DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 \
    docker run -d --name ddagent --network my-network -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
    -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    -e DD_API_KEY="{{ result.stdout }}" \
    datadog/agent:latest
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment on same. 
I did try the approach but held up in error regards to path of .py script 

Error : {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/centos/conf.d/ssmread/ddkeyreadssm.py", "msg": "[Errno 8] Exec format error", "rc": 8}

here "/home/centos/conf.d/ssmread/ddkeyreadssm.py" is the path where i have my .py file.

Also do we need to add "python3" right before the path reference in .yml ?? 
Presently its as 


`- name: run python script
      command: "/home/centos/conf.d/ssmread/ddkeyreadssm.py"
      register: result`

Comment: There may be other ways but type ```which python3``` you will get the path to python executable, then modify the ```command``` module accordingly. Updated the answer.